# delete checked item from database Django

Tags: python, django, checkbox, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to delete the selected row when "Delete" button has been selected after the checkbox for the row-to-be-deleted has been checked. I have no idea which part of my code is wrong and cause the particular row wasn't deleted from database when the checkbox has been checked and "Delete" button has been selected. Right now, when the "Delete" button has been selected, i still can see the particular row in my table. (This means that it hasn't been deleted from Database as my table only display data stored in database.) Could anyone please identify any error in my code provided ?

**add_remove_scholarship.html**

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Selected Scholarship"   >
<form method="POST" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
    <table  id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%" border="1.5px">
    <tr align="center">
        <th style="border-top: none;border-right: none;border-left: none"></th>
        <th> Scholarship </th>
        <th> Faculty </th>
        <th> Open Date </th>
        <th> Close Date </th>
    </tr>
    {% for item in query_results %}
    <tr align="center">
        <td style="border: none;"><input type="checkbox" name="item" value="{{item.doc}}">
        <td>{{item.doc}}</td>
        <td>{{item.faculty}}</td>
        <td>{{item.openDate}}</td>
        <td>{{item.closeDate}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </table>
</form>
```

**views.py**

```
def scholarship(request, id=None):
query_results = []
if request.POST.get('delete'):
   Scholarship.objects.filter(id__in=request.POST.getlist('scholarship')).delete()
   return redirect('/hrfinance/lscholarship/')
elif request.POST.get('add'):
    form = ScholarshipForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        scholarship = form.save(commit=False)
        scholarship.save()
        return redirect('/hrfinance/lscholarship/')
else:
    form = ScholarshipForm()
    id = request.GET.get('scholarship')
query_results = Scholarship.objects.all()
data = {
        'query_results':query_results,
        'form':form
       }
return render(request, 'hrfinance/add_remove_scholarship.html', data)

class ScholarshipForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Scholarship
        fields = '__all__'
```

**models.py**

```
class Scholarship(models.Model):
    doc = models.TextField("Doc", max_length=1000)
    faculty = models.TextField("Faculty", max_length=1000)
    openDate = models.DateField("Opening Date", max_length=8)
    closeDate = models.TextField("Closing Date", max_length=20, default="Jan 1, 2017")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.doc
```

Comment: Try printing stuff to the console and see what is being passed in GET and POST request attribs

Comment: @kingdaemon i have tried to add "print request.POST.get('doc', None)
    print request.GET.get('doc', None)" these two lines in my view to see wat is being passed in GET and POST but nothing is being shown. I am new in Django please teach me on how to print stuff to console. It will be truly appreciated :)

Comment: you can print anything easily, just use print(request.POST) or anything that you want to see. Figure out what is being passed from your html form to django request.POST and why, and which execution path is being run based on those values.

Comment: i think your input delete button has to be in the form itself!

Comment: @kingdaemon you are right, have to be in the form. When the "Delete" button has been selected, the checked box will be refreshed and will not be checked but the data is still not deleted

Comment: now play with the prints and execution paths. See what you are getting, and if not expected look there.

Comment: @kingdaemon it says <QueryDict: <>> for both POST and GET

Comment: @kingdaemon i have solved the problem.

Comment: ;) ^^ Post an answer then.